# How to Access another Site Collection in Provider Hosted Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, apps-development

Iam developing a Custom  MenuItemAction action so that each listitem in the **Copy** list of site collection (**dev**) will get an option  for copying the documents to another list (**Paste**)  in site collection(**dev1**)  using provider hosted app for SharePoint online using VS2015.  I am  trying to save file with **filePath**  from **Copy** List. I had give Full Control at tenant level for the App.But i am getting  below 
**Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource** at **destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();**

Below is my code. I haven't change any  code in the **SharePointContext.cs** and **TokenHelper.cs**

I know  this is an authentication problem can anyone help me on how to implement the authentication for accessing the  another site collection(**dev1**).

```
        string filePath = "/sites/dev/Copy/TypeScript_Succinctly.pdf";
            var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);
            using (var sourceContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File sourceFile = sourceContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath);
                //file stream will be used to upload in destination library
                var fileStream = sourceFile.OpenBinaryStream();
                sourceContext.Load(sourceFile, k => k.ServerRelativeUrl, k => k.Name);
                sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
                //generate destination context
                string destinationSiteUrl = "https://tarun.sharepoint.com/sites/dev1";
                Uri destinationSiteUri = new Uri(destinationSiteUrl);
                //target realm of the tenant (This is constant per tenant)
                string targetRealm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(destinationSiteUri);
                //generate access token for destination site
                string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, destinationSiteUri.Authority, targetRealm).AccessToken;
                //get destination site context using access token
                using (var destinationContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(destinationSiteUrl, accessToken))
                {
                    //load server relative url of destination library
                    var destinationLibrary = destinationContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Paste");
                    FileCreationInformation fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fileCreationInfo.ContentStream = fileStream.Value;
                    fileCreationInfo.Url = sourceFile.Name;
                    fileCreationInfo.Overwrite = false;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File destinationFile = destinationLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);
                    destinationContext.Load(destinationFile, k => k.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    lbl_Success.Text = "Copied Sucessfully";
                }
            }
```

Can Anyone help me please.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using the App-only policy.

Ensure that in the `Appmanifest.xml`, you have given `write` permission to the tenant. Check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: @ Gautam Sheth, as mentioned  in the question  i had given Full Control  at tenanat level  in the app manifest.

Comment: umm is the `Allow the app to make app-only calls` checked ?

Comment: Check the screenshot again , there is a checkbox which is checked.